# Marker bar for C# application?

Tags: c#

Is there a marker bar component for a C# application what i could use in my application? As marker bar i mean something like *ReSharper* adds to Visual Studio:[image]

Another example for something similar (the bar on the left):
[image]

**EDIT**: I found non-free component for java http://www.sideofsoftware.com/marker_bar/doc/sos/marker/JMarkerBar.html what does exactly what i want to do. It doesnt suite for me but maybe it helps someone.

Comment: What technology are you using? Winforms, WPF, ...?

Comment: Well, just doing research so havent really desided yet what to use. Can be any of those.

Comment: It would be too hard to create one in WPF (for me) but a lot depends on what you kind of functionality you want (e.g. should it be clickable?)

Comment: @Erno: ReSharper marker bar has these yellow/green/red lines meaning different types and they are clickable and take you to that part in the code. Thats the main functionality i need. Dont really need different type of markers on the bar like ReSharper marker bar has.

Comment: I have never used it but the [Enhanced Scrollbar](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/624997/Enhanced-Scrollbar) can bookmark certain ScrollBar values and see bookmarked values on the ScrollBar itself as colored little dots, squares or bars and display dynamic tooltips when mouse moves over ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In WPF the bar is a bit like a ListBox with just a different way of displaying a 1 pixel high line for each line of text. The state of the line would influence the color of the line and selecting a line would raise the SelectionChanged event to which the textbox could respond.

Let me know if you want me to show a prototype.

**EDIT**

Here goes. You can click/select a line in the bar and the textbox will scroll to that line.

Still to add:

1. what to do when the number of lines is to large for the bar?
2. A different way to show the line that is current in the bar?
3. Keep the selected line in the bar in sync with the caret in the text box.
4. ...

These can be solved but depend largely on what you want. This should get you started.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:StatusToBrushConverter x:Key="statusToBrushConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                 SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                            Value="Stretch" />
                    <Setter Property="Opacity"
                            Value="0.5" />
                    <Setter Property="MaxHeight"
                            Value="1" />
                    <Setter Property="MinHeight"
                            Value="1" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                                 Value="True">
                            <Trigger.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="Opacity"
                                        Value="1.0" />
                            </Trigger.Setters>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>

            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Rectangle StrokeThickness="0"
                               Stroke="Green"
                               Fill="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource statusToBrushConverter}}"
                               Height="1"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <TextBox AcceptsReturn="True"
                 Grid.Column="1"
                 x:Name="codeBox" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private CodeLines lines;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            lines = new CodeLines();

            Random random = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
            {
                lines.Add(new CodeLine { Status = (VersionStatus)random.Next(0, 5), Line = "Line " + i });
            }

            this.DataContext = lines;

            codeBox.Text = String.Join("\n",  from line in lines
                                            select line.Line);
        }

        private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedLine = ((ListBox)sender).SelectedIndex;
            codeBox.ScrollToLine(selectedLine);
        }
    }

    public enum VersionStatus
    {
        Original,
        Added,
        Modified,
        Deleted
    }

    public class CodeLine : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private VersionStatus status;

        public VersionStatus Status
        {
            get { return status; }
            set
            {
                if (status != value)
                {
                    status = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Status");
                }
            }
        }

        private string line;

        public string Line
        {
            get { return line; }
            set
            {
                if (line != value)
                {
                    line = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Line");
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var p = PropertyChanged;
            if (p != null)
            {
                p(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }

    public class CodeLines : ObservableCollection<CodeLine>
    {
    }


    class StatusToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var status = (VersionStatus)value;
            switch (status)
            {
                case VersionStatus.Original:
                    return Brushes.Green;
                case VersionStatus.Added:
                    return Brushes.Blue;
                case VersionStatus.Modified:
                    return Brushes.Yellow;
                case VersionStatus.Deleted:
                    return Brushes.Red;
                default:
                    return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @hs2d, I added an example. See my answer.

Comment: had to change the xaml: <Rectangle StrokeThickness="5" Stroke="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource statusToBrushConverter}}" Height="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" /> and then the c# code: case VersionStatus.Original: return "Green"; .. etc. To get it working.

Comment: @hs2d, I don't see why you would have to do that. I bet you missed some namespace declarations that included the Brushes class. Also I am not sure why you switched to the stroke instead of the fill, but that is ok.

Comment: Ah, yes. I created a new application and everything worked like you showed. Dont know what went wrong in the last one.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the Graphics class on a panel to paint it yourself.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx

(I wouldn't use a bar graph as Teoman Soygul suggested, that's abusing components for something they aren't supposed to do. Same with the listbox idea by Erno. List boxes are made for showing lines of text, not marker bars.)

Comment: That ofcourse would be the best solution, but i havent used it before so have no idea how to do this.

Comment: ListBoxes in WPF can show anything you like. Pictures, words, shapes, lines. Why build from scratch when everything you need is there without even abusing the listbox. In fact, the ListBox is showing the text but just using a different representation.